# Why my outuput is not coming correct in this JS program

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

Here is my code for armstrong number but the result is not showing properly.
Please help me find what went wrong?

```
<script>
        let a , num , c=0, pow=1, temp, sum=0, rem

        a = Number(prompt("Enter a number"))

        num = a
        while(num!=0){
            num = num /10
            c++
        }

        num = a
        while(num!=0){
            temp = pow           
            rem = num % 10
   
            for(i=1;i<=c;i++){
              temp = temp* rem
            }

            sum = sum + temp
            num = num /10
        }

        if (a == sum) {
          document.write("number is armstrong number")
        } else {
          document.write("number is not armstrong number")
        }
```

I have tried to enter a armstrong number but it is showing number is not armstrong.
please find the bug in it.

Comment: where is close tag </script> ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with division here. I would suggest to use **num = Math.floor(num / 10);** instead of num = num /10.

You can try something like this.
inside your while loop.

```
while (num != 0) {
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);
        c++
    }
```

and after sum = sum + temp use this line

```
num = Math.floor(num / 10);
```

**Math.floor** function always rounds down and returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.